What should Vietnam rely on to name similar to Chinese?
As everyone knows, in the name of the Republic of China there is the word 民國. When translated into Vietnamese, it is called "Dân Quốc". Therefore, what factors should Vietnam rely on to name it the "Đại Việt Dân Quốc" (大越民國) instead of the "Việt Nam Cộng Hòa" (越南共和)?

I'm guessing this question is trying to ask, why was South Vietnam's Vietnamese name chosen to be 越南共和 instead of 大越民國. Why 大越 wasn't chosen over 越南 is off-topic - that's a Vietnamese history question. The proposed duplicate above should answer the 共和 vs 民國 part. Note that Vietnamese 共和 (Cộng Hòa) is translated into Chinese as 共和國.
